# The server SSL certyficate failed to verify

Tags: xcode, git, ssl, xcode-server

While using continuous integration I have created a bot. It was working so far, but now the following error arised:

[image]

Do you know how to fix it?

When I tap on `view...` button, nothing happens.

Comment: Shouldn't I trust something somewhere?

Comment: So it _was_ working, and now suddenly stopped? Is it possible that your SSL has timed out, or you need to generate a new SSL key?

Comment: Yes. It happened to me when i did push to remote using terminal i got an error like this: 'Failed to connect to git.mycompany.org port 80: Operation timed out'. Is it related to this?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: I do not know how to answer it:)

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry, I'll try to be more clear. :) 2 part question.  1) Are you at work or in a restricted internet network? 2) Are you trying to access a repository on your company's internal git instance, or something publicly accessible, like on GitHub.com?

Comment: I am in the office at work... the macos server is accessible only at local network. I sm trying to access reposotory on my company git instance (can be accessed from anywhere, NOT local only). The interesting thing: when I setup second macos server on my own mac and then create a bot on it, the error doesnt exist. Why?

Comment: @BrianaSwift On the third mac I have created another Server... and it worked fine. What certificate second and third mac owns opposite to first Server?